# Android notification show full title and text

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to create a simple notification. With this code, the notification appears as an icon in the notification area, and when I open up the notification drawer it is there...

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.midday);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Midday");
        mBuilder.setContentText("Now it is midday");
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

I want this notification content to actually show on the top of the screen, not just that the little icon appear on the top bar.

Like this,  [image]

I tried searching for this and found that...

```
    mBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
```

should help. But it didn't show the notification, only the little icon appears.

If you can help, that would be great.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you are trying to achieve? Like any graphic / screenshot?

Comment: added image what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer:

Its called a Heads-up Notifications.

This should be enough:

```
mBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
```

However, I have to add this line:

```
mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
```

Hopefully google will fix this

Comment: This only shows the title but other contents are hidden.. Any help and advise.